# How, in Python, can I negate a floating point number at the end of a string on lines that begin with a certain word?

Tags: python, linux, io

For instance the file would be like...

```
blah
blah
blah
keyword = 0.0, 8.987, 9.99, 0.0
blah
blah
blah
keyword = 0.0, 8.987, 9.99, 8.0
etc.
```

I only want to negate the last value if it is non-zero. so, after reading and editing, i would put out...

```
blah
blah
blah
keyword = 0.0, 8.987, 9.99, 0.0
blah
blah
blah
keyword = 0.0, 8.987, 9.99, -8.0    
etc.
```

I think I can do and `if line.startwith('keyword')` to find the lines I need, but will that find every line that starts with it in a file?

The thing I'm struggling with is how to check and see if that last number is non-zero.

Should i stick those floating point numbers into an array and check if that array spot is zero and if not negate? if so, how do i skip over the `keyword =` and just put those floats into an array?

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you edit your question to post your code?  Since this is your first post, you may also want to read "[ask]."

Comment: Why do you care if it's zero? It'll still be correct: `0-0` evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 1):

could try something like this:

```
my_list = [0.0, 8.987, 9.99, 0.0]
if my_list[-1]:  # will only trigger on non-zero value
    my_list[-1] = my_list[-1] * (-1)
print my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith('keyword'):
            outfile.write(line)
            continue
        prefix, num = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        outfile.write(prefix)
        oufile.write(str(-1*float(num)))
        outfile.write('\n')
```